# Django 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: django, django-models, beautifulsoup

I try to use BeautifulSoup to clean html from class, id etc. and then save them.

Clear html works fine, but when I try save this, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 754, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 792, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 873, in _save_table
    forced_update)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 926, in _do_update
    return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 799, in _update
    query.add_update_fields(values)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/subqueries.py", line 108, in add_update_fields
    val = val.resolve_expression(self, allow_joins=False, for_save=True)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

My code:

```
@shared_task
def clean_article_html(article_id):
    try:
        article = Article.objects.get(id=article_id)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass
    else:
        html = BeautifulSoup(article.body, 'html.parser')
        for tag in html():
            for attribute in ['class', 'id', 'name', 'style']:
                del tag[attribute]
        
        article.text = html
        article.save()
```

Maybe someone have idea what wrong with this code.

**Solution:** (thanks for AbdulAzizBarkat)

```
article.text = str(html)
article.save()
```

Comment: It could be something wrong with the model. Do you mind updating your question with your model class?

Comment: the `article` object is probably `None`,  your code might be going in the `exception` block, but you have `pass`ed it, so you can try checking the `exception`

Comment: `for tag in html()` but `article.text = html`. Are there missing `()` to invoke a function?

Comment: Try `article.text = str(html)`, if that does not work please add the _full_ error traceback to the question.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat your solution work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
@shared_task
def clean_article_html(article_id):
    try:
        article = Article.objects.get(id=article_id)
        html = BeautifulSoup(article.body, 'html.parser')
        for tag in html():
            for attribute in ['class', 'id', 'name', 'style']:
                del tag[attribute]
        
        article.text = html
        article.save()
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass
```

Comment: And how is this better? All you did was make the `try` block encapsulate all the logic (Bad design! keep try-except blocks as small as possible). In fact OP's original code was better (The `else` ensured the code only ran if no exception occured)